# How can i pass json array as arguments when npm run script?

Tags: node.js

I need to pass the JSON array as arguments when i run the script via command line.

```
 npm run create-object [{MODEL_ID: 1, TITLE: bench}, {MODEL_ID:2, TITLE: bench2}]
```

How can i do to pass json array like the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In package.json file, under scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "create-object": "node ./scripts/create-object.js"
}
```

Create a folder at same level of package.json and name it as "scripts".
Inside scripts folder create a new file create-object.js

In create-object.js file, put code

```
var args = process.argv.slice(2);
args.forEach(arg => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(arg))
});
```

Now execute the command,

`npm run create-object '[{"MODEL_ID": 1, "TITLE": "bench"}, {"MODEL_ID":2, "TITLE": "bench2"}]'`

you will get the json array in console.

Comment: I already try this. I gets an output like:
  '[{MODEL_ID:',
  '1,',
  'TITLE:',
  'bench},',
  '{MODEL_ID:2,',
  'TITLE:',
  'bench2}]'

Comment: Try running this, npm run create-object  '[{"MODEL_ID": 1, "TITLE": "bench"}, {"MODEL_ID":2, "TITLE": "bench2"}]'.

I have also updated the answer, and used JSON.parse(arg).